# How to get ordered results from couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-java-api, nosql

I have in my bucket a document containing a list of ID (childList).
I would like to query over this list and **keep the result ordered** like in my JSON. My query is like (using java SDK) :

`String query = new StringBuilder().append("SELECT B.name, META(B).id as id ")
                                          .append("FROM`" + bucket.name() + "`A ")
                                          .append("USE KEYS $id ")
                                          .append("JOIN`" + bucket.name() + "`B ON KEYS ARRAY i FOR i IN A.childList end;").toString();`

This query will return rows that I will transform into my domain object and create a list like this :

```
n1qlQueryResult.allRows().forEach(n1qlQueryRow -> (add to return list ) ...);
```

The problem is the output **order** is important.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to simply append an `ORDER BY` clause to the end of your query: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/orderby.html

Comment: The list is a list of String. Let's call it chlidList<String>. I need childList[0] to be the first row and so on. If I will use ORDER BY clause it will be ordered using the String order.

Comment: do you always start from 1 single document for the join? If so, why not perform k/v operations instead of a N1QL query? you will get more control vs the JOIN on the order in which you fetch the B documents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a rough idea of a solution without N1QL, provided you always start from a single A document:

```
List<JsonDocument> listOfBs = bucket
      .async()
      .get(idOfA)
      .flatMap(doc -> Observable.from(doc.content().getArray("childList"))) 
      .concatMapEager(id -> bucket.async().get(id))
      .toList()
      .toBlocking().first();
```

You might want another `map` before the `toList` to extract the name and id, or to perform your domain object transformation even maybe...

The steps are:

1. use the async API
2. get the A document
3. extract the list of children and stream these ids
4. asynchronously fetch each child document and stream them **but keeping them in original order**
5. collect all into a `List<JsonDocument>`
6. block until the list is ready and return that List.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped a lot.

Comment: And what about a paginated result? Is there a way to do it through k/v operations?

Comment: You mean for referenced documents? You could use skip and take rx operators after the from() in the flatmap

Comment: Thanks Simon. We used skip and limit.